# I am trying to create a flow in Salesforce org that will update a custom lookup field(user) to blank when the user has been deactivated

Tags: visual-workflow, query

I have created a record triggered flow: object user. I need to update the SDR2 custom field to blank, which is the lookup field to user, when the user has been deactivated.
The condition I have specified on Get Accounts element is SDR2 Does not equal Record>Active

I am getting this error when I debug the flow: This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: SDR2__c FROM Account WHERE (( NOT (SDR2__c = 'true'))) LIMIT 50001 ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:47 invalid ID field: true. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Not sure if this solution is the right one or not, looking forward to your feedback.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The filter  should be Record > User Id. Lookup fields have an ID value in them. The start element's entry condition should checkif the user is inactive.

Comment: I get this error when I change the filter to be Record> User Id: "Too many query rows: 50001"

Comment: @DenisaSeranllari If a user has many entries, I'd expect this. Instead, set the Get Records element to limit itself to X records (e.g. 200). After the Update Records element, add a Decision. If the number of records that were returned from Get Records is the same size as the limit, branch to a Pause Element set to resume "0 hours after triggering event", and links back to the Get Records element. For the default outcome on the Decision, you can end the flow, as there are no more records to process.